# Importing EasyEDA project to EAGLE

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, software, import

I have a problem with uploading my EasyEDA project to EAGLE.
Is there a way to open project from EasyEDA in EAGLE, I'm unable to find anything about it.
EasyEDA exports files in *.json* format.

Comment: Unless you know how to convert .json to .xml, I don't think what you're doing is possible.

Comment: Same question already asked on EasyEDA forum. Still unknown when it'll be supported. https://easyeda.com/forum/topic/export-EAGLE-2ea84170fe8f4c369f344802b922bf18